# Pymoo module not found even though complete package has been installed

Tags: python, pymoo

Trying to run a NSGA2 optimization problem, but this error keeps popping up:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymoo.model'

I have already downloaded pymoo in the terminal and updated it to the latest version
Only trying to import model is not working...pymoo.algorithim and others are found.

Tried to fix it by reinstalling pymoo

Comment: Please add your full `traceback` and are you sure you installed it into an `env` and not sourced it or the opposite way around?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no such thing as `pymoo.model`.  It does not exist.  Why are you trying to import something that does not exist?